# R: how to remove certain rows in data.frame

Tags: r, subset

```
> data = data.frame(a = c(100, -99, 322, 155, 256), b = c(23, 11, 25, 25, -999))
> data
    a    b
1 100   23
2 -99   11
3 322   25
4 155   25
5 256 -999
```

For such a data.frame I would like to remove any row that contains -99 or -999. So my resulting data.frame should only consist of rows 1, 3, and 4.

I was thinking of writing a loop for this, but I am hoping there's an easier way. (If my data.frame were to have columns a-z, then the loop method would be very clunky). My loop would probably look something like this

```
i = 1
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if(data$a[i] < 0){
    data = data[-i,]
  }else if(data$b[i] < 0){
    data = data[-i,]
  }else data = data
}
```

Comment: if you read the data in like this, you could use something like `read.csv('file.csv', na.strings = c('NA','-99','-999'))` instead and remove `NA`s which is more straight-forward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
ind <- Reduce(`|`,lapply(data,function(x) x %in% c(-99,-999)))
> data[!ind,]
    a  b
1 100 23
3 322 25
4 155 25
```

Comment: @BondedDust Did you mean to edit that into your answer? ;) (For the record, I prefer yours.)

Comment: Accidental drive-by edit. Not paying enough attention. Please forgive.

Answer (score 6):

```
 data [ rowSums(data == -99 | data==-999) == 0 , ]
    a  b
1 100 23
3 322 25
4 155 25
```

Both the "==" and the "|" (OR) operators act on dataframes as matrices, returning a logical object of the same dimensions so rowSums can succeed.

Comment: `data[rowSums(sapply(data,\`%in%\`,c(-99,-999)))==0,]` as a variation that might be more easily extensible.

Comment: I suppose that might be more extensible for larger numbers of possible missing value markers, but in this case I think mine is still more and self-documenting.

Answer (score 1):

@rawr's comment probably makes the most sense to do this during importing. Nevertheless, you can do similar if you already have the data:

```
na.omit(replace(data, sapply(data,`%in%`,c(-99,-999)), NA))
#    a  b
#1 100 23
#3 322 25
#4 155 25
```