# in R - How can I remove specific columns in data.frame?

Tags: r, if-statement, subset

In this data.frame:

[image]

I want to remove some columns that `"Total" == 0`

I reviewed some questions about my problems in here and I found it

[R: how to remove certain rows in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304723/r-how-to-remove-certain-rows-in-data-frame)

but I can't apply perfectly in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the "Total" in the "x' column denotes the last row (I have no reason to think otherwise),  we subset the last row (`nrow(df1)`) and remove the first column (as it is non-numeric), check whether that is not equal to 0.  We get a logical `vector` from that.  Concatenate (`c`) with `TRUE` so that we can also get the first column i.e. "x" in the subset dataset.

```
df1[c(TRUE,df1[nrow(df1),-1]!=0)]
#      x v2 v3
#1     a  1  0
#2     b  3  1
#3 Total  4  1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(x= c('a', 'b', 'Total'),
     v1= c(0,0,0), v2= c(1,3,4), v3=c(0, 1,1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering!!! It worked perfectly!!! I learnded so much about your kindness!!